# C# - Connection oriented layer upon UDP

Tags: c#, .net, udp

**What I seek**

I would like to know if anyone knows about efforts trying to make an connection oriented layer upon UDP in .Net. This would ease my work as I would not have to invent this all over again as I need to ensure the benefits of an network oriented connection (e.g. loss and order of received packets.)

**Background**

I want direct communication between devices behind NATs.
Due to constraints with TCP, Hole Punching and NAT, I think I need to use UDP as the protocol for communicating between the devices (e.g. silverlight 4 apps or mobile devices). I made the hole UDP hole punching work, so based on this I have decided to go on with a UDP-solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **Reliable UDP**. One implementation is [here](http://rudp.codeplex.com/), I'm sure there are many more out there. Use google and pick the one you like best.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the proper notion of the concept :)